# Render a users Lync status in a display template

Tags: display-template

I'm trying to render the author field in a custom display template to show the Lync presence icon.

I would like to get a result similar to this template that displays the presence and the name. But i'm fairly new to display templates, and very new to JavaScript so i don't really know where to look and after what.

[image]

I was looking through some different OOTB templates and stumbled over the one called **Common Hover Panel Body** and there seem to be some JavaScript doing the work in there but i'm unsure what to extract. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Are you looking to create a custom display template in which you would want to have such lync presence?

Answer (score 0):

You can investigate the code generated for presence indicator and the user, using developer tools. See this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I don't see how the CSS would help me.. i did use the debugger to see what templates was loaded on the image in my question and found a template that renders a user but i'm unsure what i really need to copy to make it functional.